# Can't write double left join using Esqueleto

Tags: haskell, esqueleto

I have a database schema with teachers, schools, and districts.  The `TEACHERS` table has a nullable `SCHOOL_ID` column (a teacher may or may not belong to a school) and the `SCHOOLS` table has a nullable `DISTRICT_ID` column (a school may or may not belong to a district).

Using Esqueleto, I want a list of teachers, each with a school (if they belong to one) and a district (if they belong to a school that belongs to a district).  It took a little while to figure out the right expression just for the teacher->school left join, but I eventually got it right:

```
select $
from $ \(teacher `LeftOuterJoin` school) -> do
  on (teacher ^. TeacherSchoolId  ==. school ?. SchoolId)
  return (teacher, school)
```

I tried adding another left join on `DISTRICTS` using an analogous expression:

```
select $
from $ \(teacher `LeftOuterJoin` school `LeftOuterJoin` district) -> do
  on (school  ^. SchoolDistrictId ==. district ?. DistrictId)
  on (teacher ^. TeacherSchoolId  ==. school   ?. SchoolId)
  return (teacher, school, district)
```

But I get an error:

```
Couldn't match type ‘Entity School’ with ‘Maybe (Entity School)’
Expected type: SqlExpr (Maybe (Entity School))
  Actual type: SqlExpr (Entity School)
In the first argument of ‘(?.)’, namely ‘school’
In the second argument of ‘(==.)’, namely ‘school ?. SchoolId’
```

Can this double join be expressed using Esqueleto?  If so, how?

Comment: I don't know this library, and it all looks complicated, but it kind of looks like you need to lift some `Maybe` stuff to sync up with the SQL stuff. Or the other way 'round. I dunno.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing

```
 on (teacher ^. TeacherSchoolId  ==. school   ?. SchoolId)
```

To

```
 on (teacher ^. TeacherSchoolId  ==. just (school   ?. SchoolId))
```

If that doesn't work, slap 'just' on other components of the query expression until it works.

Reference: used Esqueleto recently on a commercial project

Update, 2016/10/26:

I recently encountered this problem. I think it's a Persistent serialization problem interacting with Esqueleto's willingness to pretend the join doesn't produce nullable results.

I recently changed a fragment of a query from:

```
  person  `LeftOuterJoin`
  personExtra
 ) -> do
  on ((personExtra ^. PersonExtraPerson) ==. (person ^. PersonId))
```

to:

```
  person  `LeftOuterJoin`
  personExtra
 ) -> do
  on ((personExtra ?. PersonExtraPerson) ==. just (person ^. PersonId))
```

I also changed the return type of my query from `Entity PersonExtra` to `Maybe (Entity PersonExtra)`.

Now Persistent expects the possibility of a `PersistNull` and the query works fine for me.

Comment: I've tried all sixteen combinations of having and not having `just` around each of the four arguments to the two `==.` operators.  None of them results in compilable code.

Comment: @Sean what's with the `?.` ?

Comment: It's "to project a field from a Maybe (Entity a)" according to the Esqueleto docs.

Comment: @Sean try flipping those around to `^.` with the aforementioned combinations of `just` as well. I know the combinatorics / situation is ridiculous but type-based reasoning in Esqueleto is pretty hard. There's a fair bit of arbitrary behavior.

Comment: Is there a saner package everyone should use instead?

Comment: The only variation using only `^.` that compiled was to put it on the right-hand side of both `==.` operators.  That produced a runtime error `PersistMarshalError "int64 Expected integer, recevied: PersistNull`.

Comment: Need to fix the type so it mentions that the column may not exist, then fix the query if needs be (possibly with `just`)

Comment: @dfeuer I haven't found anything better yet. I've tried everything announced on the mailing list. I'm not happy with this either.